# How to clear the space below a key on a transparent pngcairo gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, transparency, legend

On a plot with a white background , the space below a key can easily be cleared with:

```
set key opaque
```

This command actually draws a white rectangle below the key, so that any plotted lines no longer interfere with the `inside` key.

However, when the output terminal is `pngcairo transparent` the white rectangle is undesired.

[image: opaque key in gnuplot]

How do I obtain a completely transparent plot with the space cleared below the key (no interfering plotted lines)? Or should I file an enhancement request with gnuplot?

### What I currently have

[image: ist]

### What it should be

I have been messing around with [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) to get this. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) would work too. However, native support in gnuplot would offer the best graphic result.

[image: soll]

Comment: I opened a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/438/) with `gnuplot`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the time being, I created a nearly empty plot with only a transparent key.
This plot is then manually combined with the plot containing the opaque key using layers in [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/). However, I could automate this with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) to obtain a fully automated solution.

Here is how to create a plot with just one data point at the origin for each dataset.

```
plot \
"<echo '0 1'" ti "14.000 MHz" ax x1y1 w lines ls 1, \
"<echo '0 1'" ti "14.174 MHz" ax x1y1 w lines ls 1 lw 2, \
"<echo '0 1'" ti "14.350 MHz" ax x1y1 w lines ls 1, \
"<echo '0 1'" ti "21.000 MHz" ax x1y1 w lines ls 4, \
"<echo '0 1'" ti "21.224 MHz" ax x1y1 w lines ls 4 lw 2, \
"<echo '0 1'" ti "21.450 MHz" ax x1y1 w lines ls 4, \
"<echo '0 1'" ti "28.000 MHz" ax x1y1 w lines ls 3, \
"<echo '0 1'" ti "28.500 MHz" ax x1y1 w lines ls 3 lw 2, \
"<echo '0 1'" ti "29.100 MHz" ax x1y1 w lines ls 3
```

Comment: Alternatively you can put the key outside of the plot borders with `set key outside`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot cover some visible lines with a transparent rectangle, you simply have to filter out the "unwanted" data.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0 and with some adaptions probably also with earlier versions)

```
### filter out data 
reset session

FILE = "SO35676112.dat"

# create some test data
set table FILE
    plot [0:50] for [a=1:10] '+' u (x):(a*0.1*(x-25)**2)
unset table

set term pngcairo size 640,384 font ",10" transparent
set output "SO35676112.png"

set yrange [0:150]
set key at graph 0.95, 0.9

# Define your filter function and define a rectangle via the values (x1,y1,x2,y2) 
# (unfortunately manually) where you want to blank out your data.
x1 = 38
y1 = 61
x2 = 48
y2 = 138
myFilter(x,y) = x>x1 && x<x2 && y>y1 && y<y2 ? NaN : y

plot for [i=0:9] FILE u 1:(myFilter($1,$2)) index i w l lw 2 ti sprintf("%g MHz",i)
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:** (in front of checkerboard pattern)

[image]