# How to show a grid with two filled plots

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting to datasets with 'fillsteps' one below another and I want the plot two show only the area that is a difference between the two

```
plot [0:1][0:1] x with fillsteps above fill solid not,x**2 with fillsteps above fill solid lc rgb 'black' not
```

But the grid obviously gets blocked in this case:
[image]

Is there any way to create something like a cross-section between the two areas, show the grid and get rid of those nasty artifacts that are seen below?

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you are asking for. The script you show is not the full script to reproduce your graph! What terminals and other settings are you using? Do you need steps or would a smooth curve be fine? What do you mean with "cross-section"? Do you mean "overlap"? Between which two areas? I see one violet area and two black areas. Please clarify.

Comment: Well, I omitted the background/foreground commands because they do not contribute anything to what the problem is. What I wanted is the following. I have one dataset (curve, steps, whatever) plotted with filled area from the X axis up to the data. Then I have a second dataset plotted exactly like the first below. This second dataset "eats up" an area from the X axis, so I want to see what is left from the first one. So, I figured to draw the first one in color and the second one with the background. But it washed out the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, basically you want to fill the area between two curves (either lines or steps) and have a grid on top. The `set grid front` you found yourself, but let me make another suggestion.

- For the first case (lines), i.e. a fill between lines, you can simply use 3 columns (check `help filledcurves`) and then the area will be filled between the curves:

```
plot '+' u 1:(f1(x)):(f2(x)) w filledcurves
```

- For the second case (steps), I don't see (yet) such an option with `filledsteps`. Actually, from your option `above` I assume you are using gnuplot5.5.

In general, I wouldn't call it a "clean" solution if you plot something and partly have to cover it with something else with background color. What if you want a transparent background? A transparent color which covers something colored has not yet been invented ;-), there is no such "invisible" color. For another example check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219551/7295599).
Furthermore, `with fillsteps` I can also observe the artifacts of vertical gap lines which you see in your graph, but I don't have a good solution to avoid them.

Hence, my suggestion is to plot only there where you need something to plot. Actually, you can mimic the `fillsteps` behaviour. It's not obvious how to do it, but not too difficult. While you plot line by line, you remember the previous x-value and function values of `f1(x0)` and `f2(x0)` in `x0`, `y0` and `y2`, respectively. You plot with the plotting style `boxxyerror` (check `help boxxyerror`) using `x:y:xlow:xhigh:ylow:yhigh`.

**Script:** (works with at least gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### plotting style filledcurves and mimic fillsteps "between"
reset session

f1(x) = x
f2(x) = x**2

set xrange[0:1]
set yrange[0:1]
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y front lw 1.3
set style fill solid 1.0 border
set samples 50

set multiplot layout 2,1

    plot '+' u 1:(f1(x)):(f2(x)) w filledcurves

    plot x1=y1=y3=NaN '+' u (x0=x1,x1=$1):(y0=y1,y1=f1($1),y2=y3,y3=f2($1)):(x0):(x1):\
                         (y0):(y2) w boxxy

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:** (download the PNG image and check that the background is transparent).

[image]

Comment: Yeah. This seems like a much more clean solution. I have to figure out your second 'plot' command, I did not use it in such a fashion yet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
set grid front
```

works in this case